# there is no info of author in git-timemachine

Tags: git

git-timemachine is good to use, but how to show author (committer) along side with the commit message?This information sometime is important for me

Comment: I think you should rather direct this question to author of git-timemachine.  They'll be able to really answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty way to display commit author (not committer, if you want that, replace `%an` with `%cn`) by advising `git-timemachine--show-minibuffer-details`. Usually, you should ask the package author for the feature request.

```el
(defun git-timemachine--show-minibuffer-details-add-anthor (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let* ((old-details (let (message-log-max)
                       (apply orig-fun args)))
        (commit (caar args))
        (default-directory git-timemachine-directory)
        (author (substring
                 (shell-command-to-string
                   (concat "git show --format=%an --no-patch "
                           commit))
                 0 -1)))
    (message (concat old-details " " author))))

(advice-add 'git-timemachine--show-minibuffer-details
             :around #'git-timemachine--show-minibuffer-details-add-anthor)
```

Comment: It has now been implemented in a more integrated fashion, no need for this advice.